# Crashlytics does not show exception type and reason

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I am using Crashlytics to log crashes. The crash logs are Symbolicated but it only shows line at which it crashed (Usually first or last line of a method). It does not show exception type or reason for exception. Do need to enable something to get more detailed logs ? Please find raw information about the crash below.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Zilingo Sellers                0x1002520e8 specialized RegularPendingOrderPickupSummarySource.getBySubOrderId(RegularPendingOrderPickupSummarySource) -> (String) -> PendingOrderPickupSummary? (RegularPendingOrderPickupSummarySource.swift:108)
1  Zilingo Sellers                0x100251708 _TTWC15Zilingo_Sellers38RegularPendingOrderPickupSummarySourceS_31PendingOrderPickupSummarySourceS_FS1_15getBySubOrderIduRq_S1__fq_FSSGSqCS_25PendingOrderPickupSummary_ (RegularPendingOrderPickupSummarySource.swift:68)
2  Zilingo Sellers                0x100219b18 PendingOrderPickupOrderSummarySection.__allocating_init(PendingOrderPickupOrderSummarySection.Type) -> (subOrderId : String, viewController : PendingOrderPickupViewController) -> PendingOrderPickupOrderSummarySection (PendingOrderPickupOrderSummarySection.swift:17)
3  Zilingo Sellers                0x100194f74 specialized PendingOrderPickupViewController.initSections(PendingOrderPickupViewController) -> (String) -> () (PendingOrderPickupViewController.swift:30)
4  Zilingo Sellers                0x100193838 PendingOrderPickupViewController.initSections(PendingOrderPickupViewController) -> (String) -> () (PendingOrderPickupViewController.swift:28)
5  Zilingo Sellers                0x10025e638 _TTSf4g_g_d___TFC15Zilingo_Sellers24OrdersListViewController15prepareForSeguefS0_FTCSo17UIStoryboardSegue6senderGSqPSs9AnyObject___T_ (OrdersListViewController.swift:173)
6  Zilingo Sellers                0x10025cfc4 _TToFC15Zilingo_Sellers24OrdersListViewController15prepareForSeguefS0_FTCSo17UIStoryboardSegue6senderGSqPSs9AnyObject___T_ (OrdersListViewController.swift)
7  UIKit                          0x189049f7c -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController:sender:] + 356
8  UIKit                          0x189049de4 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 92
9  UIKit                          0x188c79b08 -[UIViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] + 108
10 Zilingo Sellers                0x10025df94 specialized OrdersListViewController.tableView(OrdersListViewController) -> (UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> () (OrdersListViewController.swift:151)
11 Zilingo Sellers                0x10025cf30 @objc OrdersListViewController.tableView(OrdersListViewController) -> (UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath : NSIndexPath) -> () (OrdersListViewController.swift)
12 UIKit                          0x188a37c5c -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1316
13 UIKit                          0x188af577c -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 376
14 UIKit                          0x188bb2fd8 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
15 UIKit                          0x188bc0990 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 92
16 UIKit                          0x1888f24a4 _afterCACommitHandler + 96
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18376c7b0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
18 CoreFoundation                 0x18376a554 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
19 CoreFoundation                 0x18376a984 __CFRunLoopRun + 928
20 CoreFoundation                 0x183694d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
21 GraphicsServices               0x184f7c088 GSEventRunModal + 180
22 UIKit                          0x188969f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
23 Zilingo Sellers                0x1001728a0 main (AppDelegate.swift:17)
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x1832328b8 (Missing)
```